# Cannot install mongodb-client-encryption (Node.js wrapper for libmongocrypt)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

So, i`m trying to install mongodb-client-encryption on a machine, without fully open internet connection (due to security reasons). Here is an output:

```
prebuild-install WARN install connect ECONNREFUSED 140.82.118.3:443

D:\WebProjects\asdsa\node_modules\universal-starter-v9\node_modules\mongodb-client-encryption>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\asdsa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\asdsa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.20.23.46:443
gyp ERR! stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\asdsa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\WebProjects\asdsa\node_modules\universal-starter-v9\node_modules\mongodb-client-encryption
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
prebuild-install WARN install connect ECONNREFUSED 140.82.118.3:443

D:\WebProjects\incidents-kcb\node_modules\universal-starter-v9\node_modules\mongodb-client-encryption>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\ShmatEV\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\asdsa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.20.23.46:443
gyp ERR! stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\asdsa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\WebProjects\asdsa\node_modules\universal-starter-v9\node_modules\mongodb-client-encryption
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Hypothetically you can download the modules elsewhere (outside the firewall) and bring them in... Unless that violates some sort of policy. But to me, this sounds like your Firewall is blocking downloads from NPM installs.

Comment: Yes, its definetley blocks, and i tryed multiple ways of bringing mongodb-client-encryption on machine withour global internet connection, still nothing helped.
P.S. I tryed to copy mongodb-client-encryption into node_modules. Also i made bundledDependencies in package.json with it. But it always tryes to connect to distant server (probably it want some binaries)

Comment: So yeah, for now it is only solution, that worked for me:
Downloaded modules outside of firewall restrictions, and copyed them into firewalled project.